# Navbar padding and border not at 100% height of bar

Tags: html, css, border, padding, navbar

I've noticed that the borders for my links do not cover 100% of the `navbar` height. Either it is one pixel too short at `padding:10px;`, or it is one pixel too long at `padding:11px;` (which to me makes absolutely no sense)

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHZSa/1/)

```
<nav class="bg">
    <div class="navwrap width">
        <div class="nav"><div class="navLeft"></div><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a><div class="navRight"></div></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.width{margin:0 auto;min-width:1000px;width:84%;}
 nav{border-top:1px solid #BBB;border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;}
.navwrap{display:flex;flex-flow:row-wrap;padding:10px 0;font-weight:bold;color:#FFF;}
.nav{flex:1;}
.navLeft,.navRight{display:inline;padding:10px 0;}
.navLeft{border-right:1px solid #555;}
.navRight{border-left:1px solid #000;}
.nav a{padding:10px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0);transition:background-color 0.2s linear;border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #555;}
.nav a:hover{background:rgba(0,0,255,1);}
```

Also, while I've been using pixels to set the height, how can I use 100% instead? I'm sure that would solve the problem, but when I do it, the padding and rollover background colour becomes 100% of page height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the padding from the navwrap div and set `display:inline-block` on the anchor elements

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YHZSa/3/)**

Comment: Cheers. That did it. I have a search form on the same bar which is messed up now, but I'll mess around with that until it works again.